# Why did Hashem confuse the tongues of the tower-builders, rather than set them at enmity with each other?

Tags: commentaries, language, parashat-noach, genesis-bereishith, tower-of-babel

Shalom.

I have tonight been grappling with a challenge to emunah posed by historical linguistics - i.e. the fact that new languages develop naturally, through the separation, or the divisions between, groups of people or individuals over time. Given this fact, and if no other factors were relevant, HKBH could have created different, distinct languages at the time of the Tower-building by setting that generation against other (by creating conflict). Instead, he did it without bloodshed / injury - by performing a natural-law defying miracle. Rashi says that the peace and unity of this generation was reckoned in its favour. Are there any sources that provide reasons why HKBH performed this natural-law defying miracle, rather than setting that generation at conflict with each other?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first of all, the Ralbag (Bereshit Beur HaParashah 11:3-9) explains that the main thing is that Hashem wanted, in His kindness, to offer protection to the human race, not wiping them out, but rather to offer protection (see also Avot D'Rabbi Natan 12:7). This is also a partly answer to your statement:

> Are there any sources that provide reasons why HKBH performed this natural-law defying miracle, **rather than setting that generation at conflict with each other?**

The posuk reads:

> And the Lord said, Behold, the people is one, and they have all one language; and this they begin to do: and now nothing will be withheld from them, which they have schemed to do.

The [Chizkuni](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.11.6?lang=bi&with=Chizkuni&lang2=en) on this posuk writes that G-d scattered them and changed their language, in order to prevent them from putting action to their evil design. This idea originally comes (according to a footnote in the commentary on Sefaria) from the [Bekhor Shor](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.11.6?lang=bi&with=Bekhor%20Shor&lang2=en).

The [Radak](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.11.6?lang=bi&with=Radak&lang2=en) explains that G-d changed their language, so they wouldn't be able to maintain the unity they once had.

> ושפה אחת, they can maintain their unity by speaking the same language.

Thus, when they have had their own language and kept it, they would be able to proceed with their transgressions and evil deeds, which, ultimately could have ended with punishment(s), and, according to the Ralbag, G-d wanted to prevent that.

[Onkelos](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.11.7?lang=bi&with=Onkelos%20Genesis&lang2=en) translates this posuk as:

> Come, let us descend [let us be revealed] and jumble their language, that they will not understand one another’s language.

So, their language was changed by G-d in order that they wouldn't understand each other anymore and the plans wouldn't be able to proceed in this way. Being a united people made it much easier to proceed with their ideology to ["make a name and reach to heaven"](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.11.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (partly my own interpretation of the above mentioned mefarshim).

Another interpretation is a Midrashic one. Sefer HaYashar [explains](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.11.6?lang=bi&with=Sefer%20HaYashar%20(midrash)&lang2=en):

> And the Lord said to the seventy angels that stand first and nearest unto the ‎throne, saying: Go to, let us go down, and there confound their language, that they may not ‎understand one another's speech. And the Lord did unto them accordingly. And they forgot at ‎once each other's speech, and they could no more speak nor understand the same language. ‎And when the builder would receive from the hands of the carrier the wrong bricks, or ‎something else he was not ordered to bring, the builder in his anger would fling it away, and ‎cast it upon someone and kill him. And this disorder continued for many days, and a great ‎number were killed in that way.

Comment: Hi @Shmuel - I might not have made myself clear, but I was specifically asking why HKBH performed this specific miracle (the instant confusion of tongues), rather than another one (creating division so that 'nature could take its course' and produce different languages 'herself' - no avodah zarah intended). In my ignorance, I cannot see why this miracle - the instant confusion of tongues - was preferable to the latter, 'more natural' one (utilizing the created laws of nature). Please correct me if I'm on the wrong track with this.

Comment: If Hashem hadn't confused them by changing their language, they would proceed with their plans. There needed to be a instant confusion of tongues.

Comment: @TomW I read from Shmuel's answer what I believe is the answer to your question: He chose that way instead of the suggested because **He wanted to maintain peace**. Is this answer not acceptable for some reason that I've missed?

Comment: @Rabbi Kaii - I've just read the above answer again, and yes, as you say, it does provide an answer to the question. Answer accepted. My apologies to the poster.

Comment: @TomW you ask really good questions and I am very glad you are here learning with us. I have learned a lot from this great question and this great answer!

Comment: @TomW Thank you for accepting and please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @Rabbi Kaii - I am honoured :) A pleasure and an honour to be here. With blessings.

Comment: @Shmuel - all good, will read more carefully next time. Blessings :)

Answer (score 1):

(Don't know if this is allowed, but regarding your challenge, I saw in the book Lashon Hakodesh By R. Klein that the Yerushalmi Megilla (Perek 1 Halacha 9) has a machlokes if they spoke 70 languages before the dor haflaga or not. Bechor Shor and Chizkuni on Bereishis 11:1 explain thats they were punished with forgetting all but 1 language, while Torah Temima says they had one common language they lost. Ibn Ezra there says languages did develop naturally, but it was the dispersal that caused them to lose their common language and develop new ones) Not what you asked, but it is what you mentioned as your original question, and the Ibn Ezra is sort of an answer. Hope it's ok